# Two tables for one model in Laravel / Default (undeletable) rows

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have two databases for my Laravel 8 project: **DB_COMMON** and **DB_SYSTEM**. The point is, that I want to separate sensitive data to avoid deleting, so I'll use one db_user (with all privileges) for **DB_COMMON** and another (without deleting or updating permissions) for **DB_SYSTEM**.It will be something like additional security layer.

And there are table/(-s), for exapmle, **rbac_role**. I want to store two roles as "system" (S_ADMIN and CUSTOMER) in **DB_SYSTEM** and allow user to create new roles in same table name (**rbac_role**), but in **DB_COMMON**. And usually I want to work with that roles in one place (one model).

Are there any way to do it?

Or, maybe, I can "push" this two roles in model? I mean merge rows from database table with my (maybe even hardcoded) rows in model?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to create two separate connection in your `config/database.php` file.
`mysql` connection is default if you are using mysql database.

Copy that params and create new connection:

```
'connection2' => [
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
  'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
  'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
  'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
  'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
  ...
],
```

Then you can specify any model to run on specific connection:

```
class RoleModel extends Model {
  protected $connection = 'connection2';
  ...
}
```

When you call `RoleModel` it will connect to second database.

I don't fully get what you want, But if you want to select from rows from two database you can set `connection` dynamically and select rows from any table.

```
$first_rows = RoleModel::setConnection('mysql')->select('id', 'role')->get();
$second_rows = RoleModel::setConnection('connection2')->select('id', 'role')->get();
$combined_rows = $first_rows->merge($second_rows);
```

If you want to create new row in second connection depending whether same record exists in first connection:

```
if(RoleModel::setConnection('mysql')->where('role', 'somerole')->exists()){
  RoleModel::setConnection('connection2')->create([
    'role' => 'somerole'
  ]);
}
```

Hope this answer helps you